# Android:Achartengine with broadcast Receiver,getBarChartView

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bar-chart, achartengine

I'm using a broadcast receiver to get Wifi informations ,and then display them into a bar chart with the acharengine. Welle what i need is to constantly chage the graphe with the values that i get from the receiver ,**in the same view**.
But what i'm getting is : in every cycle of the receiving i'm creating a new view to display chart ,i can get form example 10 views ,and i want to return i pass through those then views.
How can i acheive this work in the same view.
I have in the onReceive methode :

`Intent intent1 = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(WifiChartsRealTime.this,getTruitonBarDataset(),renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
                startActivity(intent1);`

This what givig me the intents..
There is a method getBarChartView but i dont know how to use it.
Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to recreate views just use repiant and it will do the same thing.

Comment: I used this code   GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(WifiChartsRealTime.this, getTruitonBarDataset( results), renderer, Type.STACKED);
            layout.addView(mChartView);
          //  mChartView.refreshDrawableState();
            mChartView.repaint(); ==> But the layout displays only the first result, even if there is changes on result (i sse it with toast )nothing changes on the chart,what could be the problem ?

Comment: why refreshDrawableState ?

Comment: i don't use it , it's on comment :)

Comment: you can see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056144/android-broadcastreceiver-with-achartengine-dont-display-changes) where i put the code.

Comment: Make mChartView  global and check for null in BroadcastReceiver before adding new view. If it is not null don't add a new view .If mChartView  is not null just call repaint.

Comment: you mean like this :                                                      mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(WifiChartsRealTime.this, getTruitonBarDataset( results), renderer, Type.STACKED);
           if (mChartView != null)
    {layout.addView(mChartView);}
          
           else
            {mChartView.repaint();}

    }

Comment: 1st line should also be in if block.

Comment: if (mChartView == null) {mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(WifiChartsRealTime.this, getTruitonBarDataset( results), renderer, Type.STACKED); layout.addView(mChartView);} else {mChartView.repaint();} }

Comment: i try it , but there is no update in the chart ,what should i do ?

Comment: maybe the brodcastreceiver ,is updating data ,faster then the creation of a graphe ??

Comment: Add log and see what is happenning .

Comment: i added logs and toasts ,the results are changing ,even in the getTruitonBarDataset() method ,you can see my code in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056144/android-broadcastreceiver-with-achartengine-dont-display-updates)