# WiFi Channels Graph Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I used this part of code in my `Fragment` class to display wifi channels graph, the problem is when I change from first `Fragment` to the second `Fragment` the app crashes due to an error on the `Receiver` can some one help me please ???

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        WifiManager wifiMan=(WifiManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          wifiMan.startScan();

        int length;
        List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();


        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            length = results.size();

            Log.i("length1", length + "");
            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getTruitonBarRenderer(results
                    .size());
            myChartSettings(renderer);

            chartLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(
                    R.id.chart);
            GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(
                    getActivity(), getTruitonBarDataset(results), renderer,
                    Type.STACKED);

            if (mChartView != null) {
                chartLayout.removeView(mChartView);
            }


            chartLayout.addView(mChartView, 0, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));             
        }

    }
}
```

This is my logcat out put:

```
06-17 14:36:50.778: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10263): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-17 14:36:50.778: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10263): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-17 14:36:51.799: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10263): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-17 14:36:51.799: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10263): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-17 14:36:55.012: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10263): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-17 14:36:55.012: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10263): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-17 14:36:59.167: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10263): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-17 14:36:59.167: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10263): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS flg=0x8000010 } in com.esprit.testproject.apscan.GraphFragment$Receiver@423df448
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:332)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3304)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.<init>(GraphicalView.java:91)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at org.achartengine.ChartFactory.getBarChartView(ChartFactory.java:164)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at com.esprit.testproject.apscan.GraphFragment$Receiver.onReceive(GraphFragment.java:356)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
06-17 14:37:16.575: E/AndroidRuntime(10263):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Can you post logcat output here? That will make it easier for us to tell where the problem lies.

Comment: I put it right now for you thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` in the call to `ChartFactory.getBarChartView`. So you might want to check if one of the parameters you are passing is `null`.

I suspect one of the two calls `getTruitonBarRenderer()` and `getTruitonBarDataset()` to return `null` under some circumstances. (Maybe when the WiFi scan returns no results?) Add some logic to handle these cases, and you should be good.

However, I now also see that you handle `mChartView` in a weird way.

- You're declaring `mChartView` as a local variable. The sample code has it as a class member, thus its contents would be preserved between calls.
- The sample code makes the call to `chartLayout.removeView(mChartView)` **before** reassigning `mChartView`, thus removing the old view (created when the method was last called) from the layout before creating and inserting a new one. In the code you posted above, the call to `chartLayout.removeView(mChartView)` would remove a layout that never got inserted, which is likely to throuw an exception or just do nothing.

Try replacing this piece of code

```
        GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(
                getActivity(), getTruitonBarDataset(results), renderer,
                Type.STACKED);

        if (mChartView != null) {
            chartLayout.removeView(mChartView);
        }

        chartLayout.addView(mChartView, 0, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

with

```
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = getTruitonBarDataset(results);

        if ((dataset != null) && (renderer != null)) {
            if (mChartView != null) {
                chartLayout.removeView(mChartView);
            }

            GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(
                    getActivity(), dataset, renderer,
                    Type.STACKED);

            chartLayout.addView(mChartView, 0, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
```

and additionally add a `mChartView` member to your class.

Comment: I agree with you Mr but I'am really confused because I still don't know how to solve this error :( I find this code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056144/android-broadcastreceiver-with-achartengine-dont-display-updates/23241492#23241492 can you check it for me please

Comment: I really appreciate your candidness and honesty in answering my question and trying to help me :) Thank you a lot but that's not working with me but at least now I can switch between tabs but when I click button back on my device the app crashes again :(